# Why isn't SOAP-based web service RESTful?

Tags: web-services, soap, rest

I understand RESTful is an architecture style, but what exactly makes SOAP-based web service not count for RESTful?

It's not clear to me which points below (from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer)), is not conformed by SOAP.

1. Client-server
2. Stateless
3. Cacheable
4. Layered system
5. Code on demand (optional)
6. Uniform interface

   - Identification of resources
   - Manipulation of resources through these representations
   - Self-descriptive messages
   - Hypermedia as the engine of application state

**EDIT**: I just came across [this](http://www.peej.co.uk/articles/rest.html#FFSHARE-close) which summaries it pretty well.

> REST is not RPC, RPC says, "define
>   some methods that do something"
>   whereas REST says, "define some
>   resources and they will have these
>   methods". 
>   It is a subtle but vital difference,
>   when given a URI anyone knows they can
>   interact with it via the predefined
>   set of methods and receive standard
>   HTTP responses in return. So given
>   http://www.peej.co.uk/ I know I can
>   issue a GET on it and receive
>   something meaningful back. I may then
>   try a PUT on it to change it and
>   receive a meaningful HTTP error code
>   since I'm not authorised to meddle
>   with it.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

SOAP follows the RPC pattern. A SOAP API describes a series of methods, along with their parameters and return values, that you can call from your code. There's a marshaling step that converts this into it's network representation.

REST is never RPC. A REST API describes a series of resources, along with a set of verbs (typically HTTP's GET, POST, PUT, DELETE) that can act on them.

To answer your question directly: SOAP primarily violates point 6 (it doesn't provide a uniform set of verbs across APIs). It also violates point 2 (the server can maintain state for each client), and as a result point 3 as well (state prevents caching).

Comment: SOAP can be ReSTful.  Just because SOAP allows for unrestful things (as well as restful), doesn't mean it can't be restful.

Comment: @Physics-Compute Not really. SOAP always uses an HTTP POST, with the request contained in the body. You can't make use of the other HTTP verbs, which is counter to the idea behind REST. (Not cacheable, non-uniform interface, not HATEOAS, etc.)

You could *encapsulate* a RESTful API inside of a SOAP API, but the SOAP protocol itself cannot be RESTful.

Comment: Just because it only uses a single verb does not mean it disqualifies it.  It certainly is cachable and may have a uniform interface.  Again, just because it has the ability NOT to be restful doesn't mean it can't be.  The protocol allows it to be or not to be.  That is the question.

Comment: @Physics-Compute Using multiple, standardized methods is a requirement, per Fielding. While you could emulate a REST-style interface in SOAP, I'd argue it still won't meet the "Uniform Interface/HATEOAS" requirements. At best, it'd be an academic exercise and counter to users' expectations. One of the nice things about REST is that it shares the same hypermedia interface as the rest of the web. No matter what you do, I can't make a SOAP call from my browser's address bar. See: http://whatisrest.com/rest_constraints/uniform_contract_profile

Answer (score 55):

REST and SOAP are not equivalent concepts.

REST:

- Depends on one transport protocol (HTTP).
- Makes full use of the specific features of that protocol (verbs GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, caching, headers, and predefined error codes).
- Says nothing about the format of the messages passed back and forth. However, since the HTTP verb and URL already define the action to take, the message body must therefore contain only the data.
- Message security is provided by the transport protocol (HTTPS), and is point-to-point only. If you want to secure the message end-to-end, you have to do it yourself.
- Originally intended for simple CRUD operations on objects.

SOAP:

- Independent of the transport protocol (could be HTTP, FTP, TCP, UDP, named pipes, shared memory or even email).
- Requires only that the transport protocol be able to send and receive text (e.g. on HTTP, only the POST verb is used).
- Strictly defines the format of the messages passed back and forth. A SOAP message contains the data, the action to perform on it, the headers, and the error details in case of failure.
- Message security is provided by the WS-* standards, and is end-to-end.
- Originally intended for arbitrary RPC calls.

Items 2 and 3 in the above lists are the main points of incompatibility.

Comment: -1 for REST depends on HTTP and "message body must only contain the data" -- uh, HATEOAS says otherwise and CRUD is orthogonal to REST.

Comment: @Doug: The message body does contain only data; I deliberately avoided specifying what sort of data. I also said that REST can be used for CRUD operations, not that REST = CRUD. My answer is not intended to explain REST or HATEOAS in great detail, merely to list where they differ from SOAP.

Comment: I can understand not going in deep, and I thought starting out that they are not equivalent concepts was spot on. Perhaps there's a better way to contrast them - especially without saying things like REST is only one protocol but SOAP is protocol independent. For example, you might rather have said that REST is an architectural constraint that utilizes the transfer protocol, whereas SOAP tunnels through it.

Comment: +1. SOAP  is a *protocol* whereas REST is an *architectural style*

Comment: Can you please explain what are the areas where SOAP is more preferable than REST ?

Comment: @Kishan: I would use SOAP when I wanted either transport protocol independence, or end-to-end encryption, or an RPC-style API. For everything else, you can use REST.

Answer (score 5):

One of the objectives of REST is cachability, for that the resource needs to be identified by the uri (query string). In soap the request is posted, therefor for different requests you have the same uri and thus the resource cannot be uniquely identified by the ur

Comment: That doesn't mean it can't be cached.  You can cache by a uri + posted data.  Different style of caching for sure, but still cachable.

Answer (score 4):

REST conforms to nothing more than the http protocol.

Answer (score 2):

**Restful :**
REST is architectural style for building web service using HTTP protocol, where web services are treated as resources and some basic HTTP methods like GET, POST, DELETE are used
to identify standard action on resources.
RESTful web API (also called a RESTful web service) is a web API implemented using HTTP and the REST principles.

**Soap :**
SOAP, originally defined as Simple Object Access Protocol, is a protocol specification for exchanging structured information in XML form.

Answer (score 2):

**SOAP vs REST Web Services**

1)  SOAP is a protocol whereas REST is an architectural style.

2)  SOAP can't use REST because it is a protocol whereas REST can use SOAP web services because it is a concept and can use any protocol like HTTP, SOAP.

3)  SOAP uses services interfaces to expose the business logic whereas REST uses URI to expose business logic.

4)  SOAP defines standards to be strictly followed whereas REST does not define too much standards like SOAP.

5)  SOAP requires more bandwidth and resource than REST whereas REST requires less bandwidth and resource than SOAP.

6)  SOAP defines its own security while RESTful web services inherits security measures from the underlying transport.

7)  SOAP permits XML data format only whereas REST permits different data format such as Plain text, HTML, XML, JSON etc.

*RESTful web services are heavily preferred over SOAP web services.*

Answer (score 1):

SOAP Protocol:
SOAP is a protocol which means that it has a defined structure to it.

1. POST : The SOAP request always requires a HTTP body, hence the HTTP method is POST. More about HTTP Methods in a future POST (these are very relevant in REST), but for now lets assume this is always POST in case of SOAP
2. SOAP Action : Empty means, intent in HTTP Request URI.
3. Content-Type : SOAP uses XML as the language for communication and hence this is always text/xml
4. with the XML Namespace (xmlns) is required to indicate that this is a SOAP Request.
5. is the root SOAP element which describes the Request and Response.

RESTful API Design involves breaking the system in terms of resources, and providing access to those resources through endpoints (also called operations) defined on the web service's base uris. Access is  done using standard HTTP Methods and controlled by an auth mechanism. Configuration for the resource is provided and obtained through request and response with HTTP status codes communicating the status.
1. Resources are the entities that exist in the system being made RESTful. For instance, in case of a blogging website, these can be the blogs, posts and comments.
2. EndPoints or operations provide a mechanism through which these resources can be accessed. For instance, the endpoint to list all the blog posts on a particular blog would be a GET on /blogs/{blogId}/posts. 
3. Base URIs  define the web uri location where the resources are available through the endpoints. To take a real example, for Google blogger the base_uri is https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3.
4.  HTTP Methods is where the simplicity of REST lies. In RESTful API design, operations on resources are  done through the standard HTTP methods, primarily GET, POST, PUT and DELETE . Other HTTP methods - OPTIONS, HEAD, PATCH are also used in some cases.