# what should i know before using a webservice

Tags: java, web-services

I made a program call a webservice GeoIpService using wsimport for knowing ip location. but it look like local class method call program written in java.because wsimport give classes for use.
i call in main method

```
            String ipAddress = "17.21.55.143";
    GeoIPService geoIPService = new GeoIPService();
    GeoIPServiceSoap geoIPServiceSoap = geoIPService.getGeoIPServiceSoap();

    GeoIP geoIP = geoIPServiceSoap.getGeoIP(ipAddress);
    System.out.println(geoIP.getCountryName());
```

for using this web service i have to know so many thing like,

1- which generated class will give the ip location information.

2- i have to go through a pre defined process for getting ip address
   create a instance of GeoIPService , create instance of GeoIPServiceSoap by calling                     getGeoIPServiceSoap() method and so many..................

i am new to learn webservice,so i have so many doubt about this

- what should exactly know before using a webservice.do i have to know what kind of information provided by a webservice if yes how.
- using wsimport i have generated classes. how i know which class going to give me information and what is the procedure to get the right information without exception.how user does know and user may be a java client or dotnet client or c++ client.
- is each language client generate language specific library using same WSDL with own tools.for example in java wsimport.
- may i am asking many silly question. but i really confuse regarding webservice what information must we have before using a webservices written in any language from a java client.

Thank's.

Comment: `wsimport` generates code using the wsdl (it's not a download)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10557514/different-types-of-webservices-in-java-where-to-start?rq=1 might be a good read

Comment: @RC. my mistake sorry.change to generated.