# How to store data on online database ?

Tags: android, mysql, json

I am developing application in android and I am using MySQL as a database for online data storage. For that I have to store data and read it in the form of JSON. But I am getting difficulty to do that. And in my app I had a functionality to save note,task,images,songs,recipe etc from above functionality provide any tutorial. I also want to access android phone book and save it to online database.

Comment: What is the difficulty you're facing?

Comment: i dont want to store data in sqlite. i want to store it online. and i have done mostly in mysql.

Comment: and i m using java for mysql connectivity

Answer (score 2):

There is very helpful article for your idea http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

Answer (score 2):

When mobile application want to interact with remote server database you must required a component called Webservice.  Since mobile application can not directly interact with remote database.

A Web service is a method of communication between two electronic devices over World Wide Web. A web service is a software function provided at a network address over the web or the cloud; it is a service that is "always on" as in the concept of utility computing

A Webservices can be written in different programming language like Php, .Net, Java.

Comment: @user3347459 see this example of [Php webservice with mysql](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/).

Comment: but i m using java for mysql connectivity and u r providing me solution for php-mysql.. give me any solution for my problem

Comment: That is an example. you need to code your self in Java. Google it.

Comment: @user3347459 this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10557514/3330969) might helpful for you.